# Получение настройки SharedPreferences из класса другого Activity

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть настройки. В них `Spinner` ставится на определенное значение и номер выбранного значения сохраняется в `SharedPreferences`. Как мне получить число, которое я там сохранил, из другого `Activity`? Создал такой метод в `Activity` настроек:

```
public int getColor() {
    int savedPosition = colorPref.getInt(COLOR_PREF, 0);
    return savedPosition;
}
```

Вот так в `Activity` настроек происходит установка значения:

```
public void spinSave(int numberPosition) {
    colorPref = getSharedPreferences(getLocalClassName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = colorPref.edit();
    ed.putInt(COLOR_PREF, numberPosition);
    ed.apply();
}
```

И пытаюсь получить его значение в главном Activity так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    int theme = settings.getColor();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setColor(theme);
```

Выдает ошибку в `int theme = settings.getColor();`. Хотелось бы знать, почему?

Comment: @pavlofff добавил)

Comment: от какого класса наследуется первая активити? класс `Settings` используется для доступа к системным настройкам и содержит в себе ключи-константы для полей системных настроек, а не для пользовательских настроек и не имеет никаких геттеров.

Comment: @pavlofff MainActivity наследуется от AppCompatActivity, активити Settings тоже... При наследовании от PreferenceActivity не получается стрелку назад сделать сверху, а в  AppCompat получается. То есть мне нужно переименовать класс активити настроек, чтобы не было таких странностей?

Comment: Если указан правильный импорт во втором активити, то странностей не будет, хотя использовать имена собственных классов, аналогичные системным, конечно не рекомендуется. "Странность" в самом доступе к настройкам, сейчас напишу ответ, как правильно.

Comment: @pavlofff хорошо, ожидаю. Спасибо заранее ;)

Comment: @pavlofff оставил мой старый colorPref на активити Settings, и сделал новый как вы и посоветовали (иначе возникала путаница, спиннер не сохранял положение, а смена темы была). Теперь все работает, только хотелось бы конечно проработать еще один момент... Тема применяется только после перезапуска приложения, а мне хотелось бы чтобы она применялась в MainActivity сразу после возврата из настроек. Как можно полностью перезагрузить MainActivity, чтобы после выхода из настроек в него выполнялся метод onCreate сначала?

Comment: @pavlofff Ааа, все, разобрался)) Оставил один SharedPreferences)

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff вчера пилил NavigationDrawer, что-то подзабыл что надо отметить как решение ваш ответ) Спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно обращаться непосредственно к экземпляру класса общих настроек `SharedPreferences` во втором активити, а не к геттеру в первом активити. Экземпляр `SharedPreferences`, получаемый через метод `getSharedPreferences()`, дает доступ к файлу настроек в пределах всего приложения и вы можете получить нужное значение, просто обратившись к новому экземпляру в любом из активити своего приложения.

Класс настроек:

```
public class MySettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

    public static final String PREF = "myprefs";
    public static final String COLOR_PREF = "colorPref";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ed = sharedPrefs.edit();
         ...
    }

    public void spinSave(int numberPosition) {
        ed.putInt(COLOR_PREF, numberPosition);
        ed.apply();
    }
}
```

Во втором активити получаем значение:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

    public static final String PREF = "myprefs";
    public static final String COLOR_PREF = "colorPref";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int theme = sharedPrefs.getInt(COLOR_PREF, 0);

         ...
    }

}
```

Так же вы можете установить слушатель [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) на изменение файла настроек `SharedPreferences`, тогда вы сможете реагировать  на изменение определенной настройки непосредственно в момент ее изменения  в любой активити приложения, но это используется обычно в наследниках `PreferenceActivity`, чтобы настройки применялись сразу при их изменении и в  случае вашего вопроса это излишне. Подробнее [по работе с слушателем изменения настроек](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?hl=ru#Listening).

Comment: Видел еще пример реализации работы с настройками через HashMap - при загрузке приложения все настройки вычитываются в коллекцию, а в ней уже реализованы все изменению настроек и их сохранение в приложении. Сам не пользовал - но слышал что на собесах уже начинают требовать описать такую архитектуру...

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky Не вижу смысла в таких действиях. Настройки не так часто изменяются, тем более все сразу, чтобы постоянно держать их в коллекции и расходовать на это память, потом доступ к настройкам требуется, как правило, в разных частях приложения и организация доступа к коллекции из не связанных компонентов (видимо это должен быть синглтон, у которого сомнительная репутация на тех же собеседованиях) никак не покроет малых преимуществ использования коллекции.

Comment: Далее, с такой схемой мы теряем колбэк на изменения значений в настройках или его организация потребует дополнительных. существенных усилий, а выгода от схемы, напомню, сомнительна. Возможно имеются ввиду специфические задачи или вопрос на понимание происходящего. В любом случае, **описать** такую схему можно без проблем, но зачем ее использовать, нужно пять раз подумать.

Comment: Я то и сам ни разу в доках гугла такой схемы не видел, просто думал что я где-то не туда свернул в развитии в андроид-разработке)) А так на этой неделе реально одни ребята сделали ну очень круглые глаза когда я ответил что впервые слышу о данной схеме...

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky Если у вас есть возможность, не могли бы узнать у этих ребят, зачем это надо, просто я вижу одни недостатки, если речь идет именно о настройках приложения. Практикуется промежуточный вариант: класс-врапер для более простого доступа к чтению\записи настроек, это сокращает код, улучшает читаемость. Есть [и готовые библиотеки](https://github.com/GrenderG/Prefs), но зачем использовать динамические коллекции мне понять сложно, какой то скорости доступа в данном случае не требуется, фактически она будет просто буфером, так как изменения все равно нужно сразу писать в файл настроек.